# addEventListener doesn't work for element added by append method from d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, addeventlistener

my javascript code for D3js.
I was adding div tags with id 'title'.
You can check it below.

```
const movieList = d3.select('#movielist');

movieData.forEach(function (movie) {
    movieList.append('div')
        .property('id', 'title')
        .style('width', titleWidth+'px')
        .style('height', titleHeight+'px')
        .append('p')
        .text(movie.name);
});

const title = document.getElementById('title');

title.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    console.log(e);
})
```

when I do `console.log(title)` I can see `title` exist.
But when I use `addEventListener` nothing happens..

Comment: Ids have to be _unique_. Use a class instead.

Comment: `property('id', 'title')` you are setting all the elements with the same id, `getElementById()` will only find the first element with that id

Comment: _"when I do `console.log(title)` I can see title exist. But when I use `addEventListener` nothing happens.."_ - There's no `console.log(title)` in your example, and nothing that would show/explain the _"nothing happens"_ -> Please make this an actual [mcve]

Comment: Try changing the title ID to something more specific and test again. Also, provide more details about the problem, as Andreas said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments on your question give you an idea of how you might make the code as is work. But as is, there isn't much point in using D3. If you're looking to use D3, let's utilize D3 as intended. D3's core functionality revolves around selections and data binding, which you aren't utilizing above, instead try:

```
const movieList = d3.select('#movielist');


const movies = movieList.selectAll(null)
   .data(movieData)
   .enter()
   .append("div")
   .style("width", titleWidth+"px")
   .style("height", titleHeight+"px")
   // d3v5 and before:
   .on("click", function(d) {
     // do something with the datum bound to each div.
   })
   // or d3v6:
   .on("click", function(event,d) {
     // do something with the datum bound to each div.
   })
   
movies.append("p")
   .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
   })
```

This avoids the use of a loop, binds the data to the elements (the `d` in `function(d)`, `d` is an individual item from the `movieData` array). The bound datum is also passed to child elements appended with `.append()`, so when adding the name of each movie to a child `p`, the right name is written.

The data binding makes later manipulation of the divs easier as you can do so based on the bound data, not properties of the div. The above also uses d3 to attach an event listener (for v3-v5 and for v6, use only one of these) and pass that event listener the bound datum.

There are plenty of resources explaining the selectAll().data().enter() cycle, so I won't do so here except to say by selecting `null`, we create an empty selection that when we bind data to it, every item in the data array is represented by an element in the enter selection. D3 handles the looping internally, hence the lack of an explicit loop.

Yes, you could do all this with plain old vanilla javascript - also rather easily; however, the question makes use of D3 and this answer shows a canonical approach to completing the task at hand.

Comment: thanks for your answer! I learned stuff from your information! thanks!!